# cannot login to application whenever I rerun the application

Tags: java, android

I am doing a login page, following a tutorial.

My login works fine, if I login directly after I register.

However, when I run the application again, using the same login info as I've register,
It will toast a message stating that "invalid password/username",
I took a look in my database, the data is in my database
but I've no idea why I couldn't login..

This is my code:
can someone help me out?

LoginDataBaseAdapter.java

```
public class LoginDataBaseAdapter {
     static final String DATABASE_NAME = "login.db";
     static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
     public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;
     // TODO: Create public field for each column in your table.
     // SQL Statement to create a new database.
     static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+"LOGIN"+
                                  "( " +"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+ "USERNAME  text,PASSWORD text); ";
     // Variable to hold the database instance
     public  SQLiteDatabase db;
     // Context of the application using the database.
     private final Context context;






     // Database open/upgrade helper
     private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;



     public  LoginDataBaseAdapter(Context _context)
     {
         context = _context;
         dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
     }
     public  LoginDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException
     {
         db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
         return this;
     }
     public void close()
     {
         db.close();
     }

     public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
     {
         return db;
     }

     public void insertEntry(String userName,String password)
     {
        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
         // Assign values for each row.
         newValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
         newValues.put("PASSWORD",password);

         // Insert the row into your table
         db.insert("LOGIN", null, newValues);
         ///Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
     public int deleteEntry(String UserName)
     {
         //String id=String.valueOf(ID);
         String where="USERNAME=?";
         int numberOFEntriesDeleted= db.delete("LOGIN", where, new String[]{UserName}) ;
        // Toast.makeText(context, "Number fo Entry Deleted Successfully : "+numberOFEntriesDeleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         return numberOFEntriesDeleted;
     }    
     public String getSinlgeEntry(String userName)
     {
         Cursor cursor=db.query("LOGIN", null, " USERNAME=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
         if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
         {
             cursor.close();
             return "NOT EXIST";
         }
         cursor.moveToFirst();
         String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
         cursor.close();
         return password;                
     }
     public void  updateEntry(String userName,String password)
     {
         // Define the updated row content.
         ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
         // Assign values for each row.
         updatedValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
         updatedValues.put("PASSWORD",password);

         String where="USERNAME = ?";
         db.update("LOGIN",updatedValues, where, new String[]{userName});              
     }        
     public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
     {
         public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String name,CursorFactory factory, int version)
         {
                    super(context, name, factory, version);
         }
         // Called when no database exists in disk and the helper class needs
         // to create a new one.
         @Override
         public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db)
         {
                 _db.execSQL(LoginDataBaseAdapter.DATABASE_CREATE);

         }
         // Called when there is a database version mismatch meaning that the version
         // of the database on disk needs to be upgraded to the current version.
         @Override
         public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int _oldVersion, int _newVersion)
         {
                 // Log the version upgrade.
                 Log.w("TaskDBAdapter", "Upgrading from version " +_oldVersion + " to " +_newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");

                 // Upgrade the existing database to conform to the new version. Multiple
                 // previous versions can be handled by comparing _oldVersion and _newVersion
                 // values.
                 // The simplest case is to drop the old table and create a new one.
                 _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "TEMPLATE");
                 // Create a new one.
                 onCreate(_db);
         }



     }

}//close DBAdapter
```

homeactivity.java

```
public class homeActivity extends Activity{
    Button btnSignIn,btnSignUp;
    Button btnAbout;
    LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.homescreen);
         // create a instance of SQLite Database
         loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
         loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

      // Get The Reference Of Buttons
         btnSignIn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIN);
         btnSignUp=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUP);
         btnAbout=(Button)findViewById(R.id.aboutBTN);

         // Set OnClick Listener on SignUp button 
            btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                /// Create Intent for SignUpActivity  abd Start The Activity
                Intent intentSignUP=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignUpActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentSignUP);
                }
            });



            // set OnClick Listener on About button
            btnAbout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    /// Create Intent for About  and start activity
                    Intent intentAbout=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),about.class);
                    startActivity(intentAbout);
                    }
                });


        }
    // Methods to handleClick Event of Sign In Button
        public void signIn(View V)
           {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(homeActivity.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login);
                dialog.setTitle("Login");

                // get the Refferences of views
                final  EditText editTextUserName=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextUserNameToLogin);
                final  EditText editTextPassword=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordToLogin);

                Button btnSignIn=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);

                // Set On ClickListener
                btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // get The User name and Password
                        String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                        String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();

                        // fetch the Password form database for respective user name
                        String storedPassword=loginDataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(userName);

                        // check if the Stored password matches with  Password entered by user
                        if(password.equals(storedPassword))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(homeActivity.this, "Welcome," + userName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            Intent mainact=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                            mainact.putExtra("priceEdit", "floatvalue");
                            mainact.putExtra("pumpEdit", "floatvalue");
                            startActivity(mainact);


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(homeActivity.this, "User Name or Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            // Close The Database
            loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
        }

}
```

Comment: use the sharedpreference to save the username and password

Comment: can't I use login database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong and it's hard to tell without taking a look into DataBaseHelper.class, but here is my 2 cents: I have a feeling that what is happening is every time you relaunch the app (recreate the LoginDataBaseAdapter) it's recreating your DB, so first launch it creates it and you go thru registration and populate it with correct values, so those are used upon your following login. But when you leave and relaunch app it rewrites DB and emptying it as result.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but here are a few thoughts:

1. Check for lower and uppercase , you are using the below code

   ```
     if(password.equals(storedPassword))
   ```

That would need your password and stored password to match exactly.

Try to put a debug statement and check what password does the DB actually return !